# listbox selectedindexchanged removes items except the selected one

Tags: c#, listbox

Why does selecting an item on listbox modifies the list of items such that only the selected item remains. [Initially list box has "a" & "b"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9rsG.png)

[Once i click "a", "b" dissappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX9A1.png)

So whenever i click "a", "b" would be removed.

So this is how i input the string i input into a richtextbox into the listbox.

```
 `private void SubGrp_comboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BefDurAftDrivetest_comboBox.Text == "Before Drive Test" && Group_No_comboBox.Text == "GROUP 1:BUS CAPTAIN CABIN" && SubGrp_comboBox.Text == "1.1 Mechanism for release of parking brake")
        {
            CurrentRemarks_listBox.Items.Clear();

            if (Savestate.one_one_one_grouping.Contains(";"))
            {

                string[] lines = Savestate.one_one_one_grouping.Split(';');


                foreach (string s in lines)
                {
                    if (s.Equals("(This section failed)"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    else if (s.Contains("(This section failed)"))
                    {
                        CurrentRemarks_listBox.Items.Add(s.Replace("(This section failed)", ""));
                    }
                    else
                        CurrentRemarks_listBox.Items.Add(s);
                }

            }
            else
            {

                if (Savestate.one_one_one_grouping.Contains("(This section failed)"))
                { CurrentRemarks_listBox.Items.Add(Savestate.one_one_one_grouping.Replace("(This section failed)", "")); }
            }
        }`
```

So when I double click on an object in a listbox, I wanted it to reflect on to a richtextbox. But then when I click on an object, the remaining object get removed. The code is as shown below:

```
   `private void CurrentRemarks_listBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Edit_CheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (Object selecteditem in CurrentRemarks_listBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                Remarks_richTextBox.Text += selecteditem;
            }

            //Remarks_richTextBox.Text = CurrentRemarks_listBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
        }
    }`
```

Anyone knows why do my objects in listbox disappears when I click an object? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, that when you select an item in your listbox, another item would automatically be removed? Is there an event attached to the listbox maybe? Check the properties of the listbox.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: private void CurrentRemarks_listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Edit_CheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
             
                Remarks_richTextBox.Text = CurrentRemarks_listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(CurrentRemarks_listBox.Items.ToString());
            }
        
        }

Comment: @Jordec i will check through, thanks for your tips!

Comment: Quick tip, you can have styling here on stackoverflow. If you want to display code like `this();` just surround your code between a backtick ` (read, not this ' )

Comment: I've added the code that controls the listbox. Thanks